# Cannot boot Windows 10 after installing Fedora 33 Workstation for dual boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, fedora, bootloader

I created a bootable USB with Win10 media and entered the command line where I entered diskpart.

This is the result of typing `list disk` and `list volume`:

[image: List disk/list volume result]

This is the result of typing `list partition` after typing `sel disk 0`:

[image: List partition of disk 0 result]

I tried using `bootrec /fixboot`, but I'm getting "Access denied" so that doesn't work.

I tried creating a new partition but that also fails due to "No usable free extent could be found" error message.

Any help is appreciated